# Duplicating effects: Dreamweaver Pong Easter Egg Beep

Tags: .net, vb.net, dreamweaver

I don't want to actually MAKE the pong easter egg, but for anyone with Dreamweaver, try typing 'dreamweaver' into the color selection box to play a round of pong.

The bit that I want to know how it works is the bit at the end once you lose.

After your loss, it will immediately play a small tune, whether or not your volume is on. In fact, it plays whether or not you have speakers, which makes me think the sound card itself is playing the tune.

How can you achieve a similar effect, playing notes without sound or speakers, in vb.net?

I would imagine this requires P/Invoke, seeing as there is no obvious way inside the framework.

Thanks for your help!

I don't need a whole song, a simple beep or the ability to change frequency of the beep will suffice.

Comment: It may be working at a low-level with the PC speaker. I seem to recall using port 60 and 61 in assembly to do something like that. I'll see if I can find something on it....

Comment: Are the beeps similar to what you get when you print out the character `'\a'`?

Comment: Best I can do is this ( http://courses.ece.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/io-devices-speaker.html ) but it should get you started. Hopefully you can compile it to a DLL and call it from VB (I'm not sure how to do that).

Comment: @Michael Todd Can't seem to figure it out unfortunately, don't know assembly at all. @mmyers No idea what that sounds like

Comment: Go to a DOS prompt and type ECHO ^G (where the ^G is actually Control-G) and see what it sounds like. That's a BEL character and is (I think) what mmyers is referring to.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to. You can also get it by printing the character `'\a'` to the console in your program (at least you can in Java, and I sort of assumed it was standard - but it's nearly impossible to search Google for "\a" so I can't be sure).

Comment: Couldn't seem to duplicate the effect, I probably am doing something wrong.

Comment: Got it working, unfortunately ;_;. I tried it once w/o speakers on, didn't work, so I tried it WITH and unfortunately it was very, very, VERY loud.

Comment: On a side note, are you running Windows 7? According to this ( http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx ) that would be one reason why the sound came through your speakers and not the PC speaker.

Comment: Windows XP, and the computer had the sound turned all the way off.

Comment: (Wow, still works in CS3, by the way. Nice Easter egg.) And the pong sound goes through my sound card; it's the "end game" sound that hits the PC speaker. I'm still guessing it's an assembly thing; sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Yep, I found out about it in CS3. The end game sound is what I am trying to figure out, this is a bit hard lol. I might start a bounty in a few days if I can't solve this by then.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679277(VS.85).aspx

VB.Net declaration:

```
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError := True)> _
Private Shared Function Beep(ByVal dwFreq As UInteger, ByVal dwDuration As UInteger) As Boolean
End Function
```

But it may not work on 64bit XP, Vista, or Win7.